# Is there a visualization framework like JUNG for iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, graph, visualization, data-visualization

Is there a visualization framework like [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/applet/index.html) for iOS?

I'd like to implement something similar to [this](http://prefuse.org/gallery/graphview/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best graph plotting library for iOS is [Core plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/). It is very powerful, and easy to understand.

But for simple graphs you can use [s7graphview](http://code.google.com/p/s7graphview/) library also.

If you want to do it yourself, you can do custom drawing using Core graphics.